# Authentication/Authorization For Self-Hosted Exchange Servers

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/common-app-authentication-tasks) states that before an application can access the API (I'm particularly interested in the Calendar API), it must be registered with Azure AD. Is this also true for organizations that may host their own Exchange servers?

Could someone provide a breakdown of what's necessary for me to get started with accessing the API to access the users' Calendar? I'm aware of the API reference, but I'm not entirely sure what's necessary to do before I can use the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is for Office365, not self hosted ones.
You can access your local/self hosted Exchange server with Exchange Web Services by using username/password, or even your local AD if you set it up correctly.

Comment: Is there documentation for working with Calendars on self-hosted Exchange Servers?

Comment: Check out the ews managed API. There are lots of examples for accessing the calendar with that: https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api

Comment: Do you know if there's a REST API that's available? I may not necessarily be able to use the Managed API.

Comment: EWS is a REST-API - the managed thing I linked is just a more convenient way to use it. Google should get you started with basic docs, I never used it directly (without the managed wrapper).

Comment: I've done a bit of searching and couldn't find a REST API. Did you mean the SOAP API?

Comment: Yes I confused those two, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The API it is talking about is not available to on-premise Exchange Server, it is only available to Exchange Online in Office 365. This may change in the future, but currently you cannot use it in on-premise. Exchange Web Services is the way to go for on-premise.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks for the heads up. Could you point me to some reference that I can use to learn about working with Outlook Calendars on on-premise Exchange Servers? Thanks!